# DBCC CHECKDB equivalent in postgres

Tags: postgresql, status

I have a database that has some visible problems (query do not return), the problem started after a script that gave errors and not transactions where done.

In SQL Server in similar cases it is helpful to run

```
DBCC CHECKDB
```

is there an equivalent command (that returns a status report for the database) for Postgres?

Comment: What does this "checkdb" do in SQL Server? What problems are you hoping to identify? And what problems did your Postgres server have that were "visible"?

Answer (score 2):

Not my area of expertise, and as of this post, not supported.
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/55762/database-consistency-checker-in-postgresql

Datewise that's some time ago later versions seem to support something akin to it:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/pgvisibility.html

Hopefully this is a starter for you.